# OpenCV to ffplay from named pipe (fifo)

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, vlc

I've been working on piping video from OpenCV in C++. I've tried to pipe the image after processing from OpenCV to a named pipe with the end goal of republishing the stream using a webserver either with VLC or a NodeJS server.

Where I'm stuck is that the output from OpenCV doesn't seem to be processing correctly. The video always has artifacts even though it should be the raw video.

[image]

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    VideoCapture camera(argv[1]);

    float fps = 15;

    // VLC raw video
    printf("Run command:\n\ncat /tmp/myfifo | cvlc --demux=rawvideo --rawvid-fps=%4.2f --rawvid-width=%.0f --rawvid-height=%.0f  --rawvid-chroma=RV24 - --sout \"#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=200,fps=30,width=320,height=240}:std{access=http{mime=video/x-flv},mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8081/stream.flv}\""
        ,fps
        ,camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        ,camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        );


    // ffplay raw video
    printf("Run command:\n\ncat /tmp/myfifo | ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size %.0fx%.0f -framerate %4.2f -i pipe:"
        ,camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        ,camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        ,fps
        );

    int fd;
    int status;

    char const * myFIFO = "/tmp/myfifo";

    if ((status = mkfifo(myFIFO, 0666)) < 0) { 
        // printf("Fifo mkfifo error: %s\n", strerror(errno)); 
        // exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        cout << "Made a named pipe at: " << myFIFO << endl;
    }

    cout << "\n\nHit any key to continue after running one of the previously listed commands..." << endl;
    cin.get();

    if ((fd = open(myFIFO,O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK)) < 0) {
        printf("Fifo open error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   

    while (true)
    {
        if (waitKey(1) > 0)
        {
            break;    
        }

        Mat colorImage;
        camera >> colorImage; 

        // method: named pipe as matrix writes data to the named pipe, but image has glitch
        size_t bytes = colorImage.total() * colorImage.elemSize();

        if (write(fd, colorImage.data, bytes) < 0) {
            printf("Error in write: %s \n", strerror(errno)); 
        }            
    }

    close(fd);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Had to move to another project when you answered. Will verify that this answer works later tonight.

Comment: That worked very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine on mine... if you remove `O_NONBLOCK` from the `open()` call.

Also, rather than use:

```
cat /tmp/myfifo | ffplay .... -i pipe:
```

you can simply use:

```
ffplay ... -i /tmp/myfifo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
.....
 _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);

.....
 cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2RGBA);
            for (int i = 0; i < frame.rows; ++i) {
                uchar* ptr = frame.data + i * 4 * frame.cols;

                for (int j = 0; j < frame.cols * 4; ++j) {
                     std::cout.write((const char*)(ptr + j), 1);

                }
            }


your.exe | ffplay  -an -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pixel_format bgr32 -video_size 640x480 -i -
```

Comment: You should put an explanation of your solution.

Comment: This solves the problem, and it is clear to the programmer

Comment: It may be clear to some but not to all, a good answer should have a brief explanation so that I help all programmers.

Comment: If there is a specific question I will answer them,  and so it is written very clear code